# Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "length", e is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdfmake

Am trying to convert html table to pdf using pdf make but I keep getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "length", e is undefined
> [image]

Here is my code

```
< center>
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="downloadDoc()">Download PDF</button>
</center>
```

Here is my javascript code with all the links

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/pdfmake-0.1.36/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/pdfmake-0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/pdfmake-0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pdfmake/js/html2canvas.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/theme.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/withdraws_report.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/notifications.js"></script>

<!-- code for js pdf libray -->

<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadDoc() {

    html2canvas($("#le_table")[0], {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image: data,
                    width: 500
                }]
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Table.pdf");
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: Pretty sure that error message has some other information like in which code block and line number it happened on. Please always post a complete error message

Comment: I have added an image of the error

Comment: on the screenshot attached, right hand side you can this this error from listwithdrawjs. Can you also expand the error msg and check what is present in that file?

Comment: That does not even match the original error you mentions in text !!!!!???????

Answer (score 1):

Your Error Image says "htmltocanvas is not defined". just install it using `npm install html2canvas`

```js
function downloadDoc() {
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/vtest2/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/pdfmake-0.1.36/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/pdfmake-0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/pdfmake-0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pdfmake/js/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/theme.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/withdraws_report.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/notifications.js"></script>

<button id="capture" class="btn btn-success" onclick="downloadDoc()">Download PDF</button>
```

Comment: I am no expert on this but `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pdfmake/js/html2canvas.min.js"></script>` was already used

Comment: After applying changes from @Nidhi Dadiya I know get this error "Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "length", e is null"  on the "    html2canvas http://localhost:8012/SACCO-NET/js/pdfmake/js/html2canvas.min.js:8
    downloadDoc http://localhost:8012/SACCO-NET/withdraws_report.php:673
    onclick http://localhost:8012/SACCO-NET/withdraws_report.php:1
html2canvas.min.js:8:1899"

Comment: Here is my working example with PDFmake. try this. https://codepen.io/nidhidadiya/pen/abNzLrj

Comment: Also You can try more table layouts from the doc. https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/document-definition-object/tables/